# pugin-developent : Platform.getbundle("") is not accessible from xtend class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtend

i am trying to get my plug-in version in xtent class same way its working fine with java classes but throwing compilation error while using in xtend class
want to automate the tool version.

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle

class StrapbaseXMLFrontend {

    val static bundle =Platform.getBundle("id") as Bundle
        
    
     val version = bundle.version.toString()
    val static TOOL_VERSION = "3.26.0"
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the correction but its not the bundle  i am able to access getbundle method of Platform class

Comment: i am not able to access getbundle method of Platform class

Comment: did the work around by creating a java class which have platform.getbundle() add use that class in xtend class